# Weird dot in middle of Processing Kinect (v2) image

Tags: processing, kinect, openkinect

I am trying to adapt Daniel Shiffman's code for a basic Kinect (v2) depth cloud using Processing, but there is always a pixel right in the middle of the screen that won't go anywhere, which is pretty annoying. This is an example of what I mean.

[image]

You can see it seems to be right at the front and doesnt move when anything in the field of view moves.

Here is the code that i used to generate the image above, (which is a very stripped down version of what i am trying to do)

```
// imports for openkinect
import org.openkinect.freenect2.*;
import org.openkinect.processing.*;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

// dots size is dot_size*skip
int dot_size = 2;

// step size when iterating through pixel array
int skip = 5; 

// Kinect Library object
Kinect2 kinect2;

// Angle for rotation
float a = 3.1;

void setup() {
  // Rendering in P3D
  size(1500,1000,P3D);

  // start the kinect
  kinect2 = new Kinect2(this);
  kinect2.initDepth();
  kinect2.initDevice();

  smooth(16);
  
  // Black background
  background(0);
  
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  
  // Translate and rotate
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2,50);
  rotateY(a);
  
  // get current depth information
  int[] depth = kinect2.getRawDepth();
  
  // read depth pixels in kinect window bounds
  for (int x = 0; x < kinect2.depthWidth; x+=skip) {
    for (int y = 0; y < kinect2.depthHeight; y+=skip) {
      
      // compute offset for 1D depth array
      int offset = x + y * kinect2.depthWidth;
      
      // get the depth
      int d = depth[offset];
      
      //calculte the x, y, z camera position based on the depth information
      PVector point = depthToPointCloudPos(x, y, d);
      
      // compute depth modifier for colours and such
      float depth_modifier = map(point.z,1000,2048,255,0);
      
      fill(depth_modifier);
      
      pushMatrix();
      translate(point.x,point.y,point.z);
      circle(0,0,skip*dot_size);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
   
  popMatrix();
}

//calculte the xyz camera position based on the depth data
PVector depthToPointCloudPos(int x, int y, float depthValue) {
  PVector point = new PVector();
  point.z = (depthValue);// / (1.0f); // Convert from mm to meters
  point.x = (x - CameraParams.cx) * point.z / CameraParams.fx;
  point.y = (y - CameraParams.cy) * point.z / CameraParams.fy;
  return point;
}
```

Here is the contents of `CameraParams.pde` to make it easy for someone to replicate:

```
//camera information based on the Kinect v2 hardware
static class CameraParams {
  static float cx = 254.878f;
  static float cy = 205.395f;
  static float fx = 365.456f;
  static float fy = 365.456f;
  static float k1 = 0.0905474;
  static float k2 = -0.26819;
  static float k3 = 0.0950862;
  static float p1 = 0.0;
  static float p2 = 0.0;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea where this dot is coming from, and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Back when I explored the kinect depth data I used to export frames into Excel to analyze it at a glance. I would then resize cells as squares and color them automatically in function of their depth data. Seeing the data around that point may help you determine if it comes from an artifact in the data stream or if it comes from something else for a start.

Comment: To export in excel I would write in a file, CSV style, then import it from excel.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix it, it was a bit of a hacky solution, but it worked.. the pixel seems to be showing up at exactly 0 depth, so I just added the code:

```
if (d == 0){
    continue;
}
```

after it calculated the depth of the current pixel, and that worked fine. I thought I would answer my own question in case anyone else had similar problems.

I know its still lurking in the data though, so if anyone has any idea of the source of the problem, I would still like to know why it is occurring - I am pretty new to the Processing language, so I'm sure there is just something I'm missing.

But for now, at least it is "fixed"!